# Perl regex with shell

Tags: regex, perl, directory

```
my $dirs = qx(echo \$PATH);
my @arr = $dirs ~= //(.*):;
```

I know the regex has to first find a "/" and then a ":" 
I thought my regex would do that however I keep getting that the search pattern is not terminated. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You should also check your syntax: it should be `=~` instead of `~=`.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to invoke the shell since Perl makes all environment variables available in its `%ENV` hash.
Use [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to extract the colon-separated directory names from the environment variable:

```
my @dirs = split /:/, $ENV{PATH};
```

Comment: Alright thanks, I'm curious though if you would still know how to do it in regex. It's kind of bothering me now lol. If not I appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 1):

> I keep getting that the search pattern is not terminated

Your code `dirs ~= //(.*):` is indeed bizarre: you start a regex with `/` and you immediately close it: `//`.

You could use `m##` to easily know where it starts and where it ends, like this :

```perl
my $dirs = qx(echo \$PATH);
my @arr = $dirs =~ m#([^:]+)(?::|$)#g;
```

(By the way, @toolic's answer is very good.)

Comment: `/[^:]+/g` would be sufficient (`my @arr = $ENV{PATH} =~ /[^:]+/g;`)